# When can we have $(A+B)\cap C=A\cap C+B\cap C$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

With $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\}$ and any non-empty sets A,B,C. When can we have $(A+B)\cap C=A\cap C+B\cap C$? I am looking for the most general conditions (if any) such that the equality stands.
Thanks

Let's start by finding out what happens when $A,B,C\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar What if $C=\{0\}$, $A = \{-1\}$ and $B = \{+1\}$. Then $(A + B) \cap C = C$, but $A \cap C = B \cap C = \emptyset$, and yet also $C$ is closed under addition in the way you describe because $A \cap C = B \cap C = \emptyset$... I think the relation you deal with second is more subtle, though it's also possible that I'm misunderstanding your criterion.

Comment: I am basically asking for the conditions (if any).

Comment: What are these subsets of? The real line? $R^n$? Any vector space? @TKM

Comment: any subsets. I just said real analysis because those problems usually appear there. But if we can say something about the reals that would be nice.

Comment: Any subsets of an abelian group? You need to have addition defined somehow...

Comment: yes, obviously. I just to care to get as general a result as possible (if any).

Comment: It's not obvious what you are asking unless you write it down...

Comment: I asked for the conditions, so obviously one of them is that addition is defined. But if you can find conditions without commutativity that would be perfect too.

Comment: How do you define $A+\varnothing$? Is it just $\varnothing$?

Comment: Let's just look at non-empty. I love it how technical the responses get in a math forum.

Comment: @TKM That is *the* most off-topic comment I've ever read in my time here at M.SE.

Comment: Are you also assuming then that $A\cap C$ and $B\cap C$ are nonempty as well? Because you still have to deal with that on the RHS of your equality even if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all nonempty. It may seem technical, but, well...mathematics is the epitome of technicality. Here, no technicality means no mathematics (a.k.a. "Rubbish").

Comment: As I said, I am looking for the most general conditions (if any) such that the equality stands.

Comment: There are certainly easy obvious examples that can make either side empty, if that's useful